# Class specific method in list of different classes

Tags: c#, list, class

so i Have a list consisting of different classes, all inheriting from a common class. Now i want to call for a method specific to one of those subclasses but i can't seem to find the right code to do that, could anyone help? 
the part of the code where it goes wrong (can't access the enemies list):

```
if (_floor.GetRoomByIndex(CheckActiveRoomIndex()).GetType() == typeof(StandardRoom))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _floor.GetRoomByIndex(CheckActiveRoomIndex()).enemies.Count; i++)
    {
        _floor.GetRoomByIndex(CheckActiveRoomIndex()).enemies[i].UpdateBoundingBox();
    }
}
```

and here is part of my StandardRoom Class

```
class StandardRoom : CommonBaseClass
{
    public bool IsCleared { get; set; }
    public List<Enemy> ennemies = new List<Enemy>();
    ...
}
```

Comment: We prefer code *in the question*, preferable *as text*, not pictures. Your question is impossible to understand if the link goes dead and inaccessible to some people using accessibility aids. Ideally, you create an [mcve].

Comment: William, add some context to your question by adding some code of your class definitions so we can help. Just the calling code is not enough.

Comment: For future reference, you should actually post the code instead of posting screenshots of code. It's much easier for people to read/help. Secondly, your question is kind of unclear but why don't you try using a `foreach (var enemy in _floor.GetRoomByIndex(CheckActiveRoomIndex()).ennemies) { //... }` and then use the `enemy` object to call whatever you want. Also, you spelled `enemies`* incorrectly.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  thanks for the advise, i addes some code, should be easier to read now.

Comment: @Chris the problem is that my code doesn't seem like it can read the enemies list, same happens when i try to use a for each instead of a for loop

Answer (score 2):

William,

The problem is that `_floor.GetRoomByIndex(CheckActiveRoomIndex())` is not a **StandardRoom**, but a **Room** (or the base class, whatever the name)

**1/ Solution closer to existing code**
There is cast missing so that the rooms can be treated as **StandardRoom** : use the **as** keyword to cast in a safe way.

And Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY principle), declare a variable (stdRoom).

```
StandardRoom stdRoom = _floor.GetRoomByIndex(CheckActiveRoomIndex()) as StandardRoom;
if ( stdRoom != null )
{
  for (int i = 0; i < stdRoom.enemies.Count; i++)
  {
      stdRoom.enemies[i].UpdateBoundingBox();
  }
}
```

As says Olivier below, with **C#7 pattern matching** (Visual Studio 2017+), the cast can be shorter :

```
if ( _floor.GetRoomByIndex(CheckActiveRoomIndex()) is StandardRoom stdRoom )
```

**2/ The Linq answer**

`Enumerable.SelectMany` can be used to get Enemies from a Room

```
if ( _floor.GetRoomByIndex(CheckActiveRoomIndex()) is StandardRoom stdRoom )
{
  // projection to get Enemies from StandardRoom
  foreach( Enemy e in stdRoom.SelectMany( r => r.enemies ) )
  {
    e.UpdateBoundingBox()
  }        
}
```

Regards

Comment: or with the new c# 7.0 syntax `if (_floor.GetRoomByIndex(CheckActiveRoomIndex()) is StandardRoom stdRoom)`. See: [Dissecting the pattern matching in C# 7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2017/10/16/dissecting-the-pattern-matching-in-c-7/).

Answer (score 1):

LINQ has a tons of available methods. Read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) or just google 'LINQ methods'.

The method you are looking for is `OfType<T>` (see [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.7.2])). This method will only select the items in the list of the required type `T`.